# modifying a subset of all vectors in a list (without loop)

Tags: r, list, na

I know i can modify a subset of a vector like this:

```
v1 = c(3, NaN, 5)
v1[is.nan(v1)] = 0 # change NaN values to 0
```

Now, is it possible to do that for all vectors of a list like the one bellow, without having to loop into each elements ?

```
lst1 <- list('v1'=c(1,NaN,3), 'v2'=c(3,2,NaN), 'v3'=c(NaN,1,3))
```

Something like:

```
lst1[[*]][is.nan(lst1[[*]])] = 0
```

I think this can be solved simply by iterate through vector in a loop but i wonder if there is a nicer way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `lapply`. It does basically iterate through the vector, but slightly nicer than using a for loop.

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) {x[is.na(x)]<-0;x})
```

Output:

```
$v1
[1] 1 0 3

$v2
[1] 3 2 0

$v3
[1] 0 1 3
```

Answer (score 2):

If we are interested without looping, then `unlist` the `list` elements, do the `replace`ment in one go and `relist` it

```
v1 <- unlist(lst1)
relist(replace(v1, is.nan(v1), 0), skeleton = lst1)
#$v1
#[1] 1 0 3

#$v2
#[1] 3 2 0

#$v3
#[1] 0 1 3
```